# Zeptojs and $ (Global Variables)

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

At first, i tought that Zepto only defined a "Zepto" global variable if $ wasn't available. So, i decided to make those tests:

[First Fiddle - Pure Zepto](http://jsfiddle.net/eWtf4/)

[Second Fiddle - Zepto + jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/BpJAK/)

**Source**

**HTML**

```
<div id="first-global">
</div>
<div id="second-global">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var first = document.getElementById('first-global'),
    second = document.getElementById('second-global');

first.innerHTML = $;
second.innerHTML = Zepto
```

Code is the same at both, only thing that changes is the framework used.

So, as you can see in first fiddle, Zepto initializes both variables, $ AND Zepto. Isn't that(Define two identical global variables) a bad practice? There would be a way to define Zepto global only IF $ wasn't available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From zeptojs.com:

> "Zepto will only set the $ global to itself if it is not yet defined.
>   There is no Zepto.noConflict method."

So it would depend on the order of including these libraries. If jQuery is included first then Zepto won't overwrite the global `$`. If Zepto is included first, then you could use [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to make `$` point to Zepto.

And no, it's not a bad practice - `$` is the short and easy alias, while the library also has its full name as a global. BTW I hope it's purely theoretical question - why would you include both libraries on one page? ;)

`$` is less reliable than library's own name (as proved by your question). Many libraries may try to set global `$` while it's less probable that a variable like `jQuery` or `Zepto` will get accidentally overwritten.

To be sure what's behind `$` you may use this pattern:

```
(function($){
   $('selector').doSomething();
}(library));
```

where `library` is the other global variable besides `$` you want to reference (Zepto or jQuery).

Comment: Thanks for your answer ;) haha Actually, not that theoretical. I was using jquery when i ran into Zepto and while i'm busy and to avoid breaking my application i'm using both. I understood that it only set $ to itself if it's not defined, my doubt is why keep Zepto as a global var in situations when $ is set to Zepto?

Comment: jQuery and Zepto living together on one page is a non-sensical idea - Zepto was created to purposely provide some of the identical functionality that jQuery provides but without a lot of clutter. Including both libraries is like putting two different versions of jQuery on the same page.

Comment: I'm using zepto only for mobile. I plan to migrate definitely to Zepto asap, but for now, i have other priorities and prefer not to risk to accidentaly break my app for whatever reason ^^

Comment: You can write your code against both libraries if you want the cross-browser power of jQuery, but also the light weight and CSS-based animations provided by Zepto. Bu then you would do some feature detection and include one **or** the other.

Comment: Got it, makes sense to maintain Zepto variable in case some other lib override $. Guess that one more global var would not affect performance that much. Thanks, @pawel.